# How can I jump to Firefox's search field when browsing on github.com?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, github

- Firefox 111.0-1
- OS: linux 6.2.6.arch1-1

If I am browsing on github.com and hit `CTRL + K`, using the browser's search will not work.

- Hitting CTRL+K the first time opens up some spotlight-/albert-like search in the middle of the screen, except it's just for the site.
- Hitting CTRL+K the second time puts the focus in the upper left field.

Is it possible to "escape", for the lack of a better term, github.com in order to jump to FF's search field directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to focus the location field, followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> which either moves the focus to the search field or switches the combined location field into search mode.

Comment: Well... I'd prefer an instant shortcut, but your way is better than no escape. Thanks.